# Don't resize navigation bar when hiding status bar

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a application with Swift + AVPlayer and have set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to "YES". The problem with this is that when I launch the player from my UITableViewController/UINavigationController the nav bar hides the status bar automatically and the nav bar is resized.

You can see what I mean here:

http://quick.as/eOXLiv45x

[image]

Is there any way to prevent this?

Cheers!

Comment: i added your image to your question, the gif is somehow buggy though, maybe upload it on a better site to enable it beeing included properly.

Comment: Cheers, seems to be working here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so this was the solution I used in the end.

1. Set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to "NO"
2. Override the following functions in the media view controller

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .Fade)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: .Fade)
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to call `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidDisappear` in the first function?

Answer (score -1):

```
- (BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed {
return YES;
}
```

You may try this. But I'm 90% sure that this issue has to be related with some action you are executing... If you want to prevent this read the function and disable the hide functionality or maybe create another method to execute after to tell the function to keep visible.

Comment: I'm not pushing, I'm presenting modally via a manual segue and the view style is set to fullscreen.